# Integral of reciprocal of a piecewise linear function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, inverse

Let, e.g.

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x,\quad x<1, \\
1,\quad x\geq1,
\end{cases}
$$

a piecewise linear function. Does the following hold for $g(x) = 1/x$?

$$ \begin{align}
g(f(x)) &\stackrel{?}{=}
\begin{cases}
g(x), &x<1, \\
g(1), &x\geq1,
\end{cases}
\\
&\stackrel{?}{=}
\begin{cases}
1/x, &x<1, \\
1, &x\geq1.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

And congruently, with $x_1<1\wedge x_2>1$, does the following hold as well?

$$
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{\text{d}x}{f(x)} \stackrel{?}{=}
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} g(f(x))\,\text{d}x \stackrel{?}{=} \int_{x_1}^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{x} + \int_1^{x_2} \frac{\text{d}x}{1}.
$$

Comment: Yes. Yes. Yes. Yes. No idea, split the integrals at x=1 and substitute according to the cases and check.

Comment: The integral does not converge near $0$, since it is $\frac{1}{x}$... So the last intregral is well defined only if $x_1>0$. In this case, everything works.